# Как загрузить картинку с сайта в bitmap

Tags: android, url, bitmap, uri

Есть URL картинки, как загрузить эту картинку из URL в Bitmap

Comment: вам нужно именно в Bitmap? Или в ImageView? Если второе, то проще воспользоваться кучей готовых библиотек, например Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @metalurgus Мне нужен именно в bitmap, чтоб потом сохранить в файл

Comment: А почему тогда его не загрузить, как обычный файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap)

Comment: @Fasd Если ответ подошел Вам как решение - отметьте его галочкой. Таким образом вы сэкономите время другим людям на просмотр и поиск вопросов, в которых реально нужен чужой опыт, а не гуглить за других.

Comment: Этот метод не работает в android studiо, ругается на 'connection.connect();', а в эклипсе он работает -_-

Comment: @Fasd, чтобы в студии заработало, надо подключить либу с `HttpURLConnection` - она в новых версиях андроида по умолчанию вырезана как устаревшая.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо